# Форма обратной связи на сайте не работает

Tags: javascript, php, html, форма

Есть лендинг, на нем есть две формы обратной связи, которые состоят из двух полей и кнопки. Уже несколько часов промчался, но все равно не работает. Если сможете помочь, буду очень благодарен.


**Index.html(сама форма)**

```
<form action="mail.php" class="footer-form" onsubmit="yaCounter41217574.reachGoal('ORDER'); return true;">
                <div class="spacer">
                    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="ReMaster">
                    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="МОЯ ПОЧТА">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Заявка">
                    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

                    <input type="text" name="name" class="footer-form__field" placeholder="Имя"/>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="footer-form__field" placeholder="Телефон" required/>
                    <input type="text" name="form" class="hidden" value="Получить консультацию"/>
                    <button class="red-btn footer-form__btn">ПОЛУЧИТЬ КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЮ</button>

                </div><!--spacer-->

            </form>
```

**PHP (обработчик)**

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //E-mail Ajax Send
        $("form").submit(function() { //Change
            var th = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php", //Change
                data: th.serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                alert("Thank you!");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Done Functions
                    th.trigger("reset");
                }, 1000);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Помогаю: [PHP Debugging (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)

Comment: Какие ошибки? что происходит?

Comment: @Greg-- ,  При нажатии кнопки перекидывает на новую страницу mail.php(хотя этого не должно быть). Ошибка в консоли появляется следующая "Uncaught ReferenceError: yaCounter41217574 is not defined (index):1251 at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit ((index):1251)"

Comment: Отключите вызов yaCounter какие будут ошибки после?